# How to remove a layer of latex paint from oil-based paint underneath?

Tags: painting

After years of living with the problem of paint flaking off onto our floors, I’ve finally gathered the courage to remove the latex paint that our contractor painted onto the original oil-based paint on our interior doors. I thought I had it all figured out after hours of googling and YouTube, but the work is actually grueling.

[image: painted door]

In the photo above, you can see the white latex paint that I haven’t sanded off surrounded by the yellowish oil-based paint that is underneath.

Is there an easier way of removing latex paint that has painted been onto oil-based paint? Or have I done enough sanding for new semigloss latex primer/paint to adhere to the surface?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you have to use oil-based primer over oil-based paint.  You can use a latex topcoat over oil-based primer.  [This](https://buildingbluebird.com/how-to-fix-latex-over-oil-based-paint/) is an example of someone with your problem.  Sorry, I can't answer your main question (whether you've removed enough of the latex to prime over it--I suspect not, but others can talk from experience).  I just wanted to point out this ancillary flaw in your plan.  No latex primer in this case (unless you apply the latex primer over an oil-based primer, which seems unnecessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone with the same problem as me, I found an alternate solution that works way better than sanding and is less messy than using a chemical paint stripper: a heat gun. https://youtu.be/msvU8kZyOlk?si=NwLyKfLwO9smOpup

[image: Paint stripped using heat gun]

I don’t know how I missed this method before. It’s super simple and only takes like 2-3 seconds for the paint to warm up enough to be scraped off. The only downside is that it’s still difficult to scrape paint off in detailed areas, which I might just use a chemical stripper for.